# PYODBC--Data source name not found. How to get valid connection String

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am using SQL Server with Docker. I am trying to connect with pyodbc to my server but then I've got:

> pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Using DBeaver I got some details:

```
SELECT
    @@servername AS 'Server Name',  
    @@servicename AS 'Instance Name', 
    DB_NAME() AS 'Database Name',
    HOST_NAME() AS 'Host Name'
```

and this SQL returns:

```
193aeb2132e4, MSSQLSERVER, model, HDZKNV2
```

How my connection string should looks like cause this one does not work (and I guess any variation of this)?

```
'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Text Driver};
 SERVER=193aeb2132e4\MSSQLSERVER;
 DATABASE=model;
 Trusted_Connection=yes;
 User=admin;
 Password=passowrd'
```

Comment: Hi @marc_s Thanks for editing my topic - now it looks a way better! I've changed value for `SERVER=193aeb2132e4` but I still got same exception. Does't work for `localhost` either. What else could be wrong?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! After removing `trusted_connection` same exception occurs. damn! is there any third possible problem? I am sure I've Microsoft Access Text Driver on my machine (there are 4 more: SQL Server, ODBC Driver 17for SQL Server, Microsoft Excel Driver, Microsoft Access Driver)

Comment: thanks a lot marc_s! I've changed driver to `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` and changed `user` to `uid`, then `password` to `pwd` It seems I've got a connection now.  Please move this response to a new post so I could accept this answer.

Comment: Done - happy to be of help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

- `MSSQLSERVER` is the internal instance name for the **default, unnamed** instance of SQL Server - to connect to it, just use the server name (or IP address) *without* adding `MSSQLSERVER` as the instance name
- You should not have `Trusted_Connection=yes` (use currently logged in user's credentials) along side with explicit username/password - use one or the other, but not both together.
- And according to the [official Microsoft documentation on PyODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15) - you should use `DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}` and `UID/PWD` (not `User`)

So try these settings:

```
DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};
SERVER=193aeb2132e4;
DATABASE=model;
UID=admin;
PWD=passowrd
```